# Why ever stop creating quotient-algebras/algebraic-extensions etc. on $\mathbb{N}\subset \mathbb{Z}\subset \mathbb{Q}\subset \mathbb{R}\subset ....$

Tags: abstract-algebra, analysis

Using inductive reasoning it appears that doing this (forming new algebras through [extensions](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Field_extension#Generalizations) or [quotients](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quotient_algebra)) helps mathematicians study algebras whose carrier sets are lower down in a chain of inclusions by studying the algebras with carrier sets higher up in said chain of inclusions. For instance here are five quick examples:

Evaluating complex integrals in $\mathbb{R}$ becomes easier using tools which require $\mathbb{C}$

Finding exact formula for roots of polynomials becomes easier using tools which require $\mathbb{C}$

Studying bounds regarding prime numbers in $\mathbb{N}$ becomes easier using tools which require $\mathbb{C}$

Studying Diophantine equations in $\mathbb{Z}$ becomes easier if working in an algebraic field extension of $\mathbb{Q}$

Studying quadratic/ternary forms in $\mathbb{N}$ is easier using field extensions of algebraic number fields.

So my question is given any algebra why not keep taking a variation of algebraic extensions and/or quotient algebras via equivalence classes of pairs, or sequences of elements to form a new algebra and then embed the older one in it. Why not keep doing that indefinitely? Why not define I don't know lets say maybe equivalence classes of sequences of complex numbers and give them a field structure by endowing each block with pointwise analogs of addition/multiplication etc. like one would were they going to construct the reals as cauchy sequences of real numbers. Why not do this again to get another field whose elements are equivilence classes of equivilence classes of sequences of complex numbers, why not another time so we have equivilence classes of equivilence classes of equivilence classes of sequences of complex numbers endowed with a field structure? Why not keep on doing it? Why should one stop at some arbitrary point? Since each previous algebra can be embedded into the one before it, you don't lose any of the tools if working within one of the lower carrier sets, as you would had the new algebra not been constructed. So it seems aside from complexity of notation one can only gain new tools to work with that might be beneficial for proving properties of the algebras lower down in the inclusion chain, thus I'm confused why this isn't done.

Comment: You can do it and there is plenty of material on it, but the thing is that at each stage you're very likely to lose a nice property. Eventually you'll just end up with algebras that you cannot say anything meaningful about.

Comment: @CameronWilliams I don't understand the properties still hold if one finds themselves working with elements from a lower carrier set. Prime factorization of integers still holds when working with *just* integers in $\mathbb{C}$. If at any point when working with one of the algebras higher up in the hierarchy you find yourself constricted to working with elements only belonging to the carrier set of an algebra lower down in the hierarchy you can still apply all theorems that only hold for that algebra in this instance. Right?

Comment: There are number systems which extend the complex numbers $\mathbb C$ in something like the way you suggest.  Best known of these are the quaternions $\mathbb H$ (the H is for Hamilton, who discovered them).  Less well known are the octonions $\mathbb O$ and the sedenions $\mathbb S$.  There the story seems to end as the algebraic properties become weaker after the very nice case of the algebraically closed field of complex numbers.  See this on the [Cayley-Dickson construction](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cayley%E2%80%93Dickson_construction) for an overview.

Comment: Conceivably you can talk about the substructure, but then the question is: are you doing anything meaningful? I would argue that you're not.

Comment: @hardmath How can the fields become weaker if they necessarily embed the previous structures before them though? I mean I know $\mathbb{C}$ is not an order field, but if while working with complex numbers I found myself in a situation where every complex number was real I could still use the ordering properties of $\mathbb{R}$.

Comment: Yes, the complex numbers are not ordered but give the right number of solutions to polynomial equations with complex coefficients.  The quaternions are four dimensional vectors over the reals (just as the complex numbers are two dimensional over the reals), but they no longer form a field (because multiplication is no longer commutative).  The octonions and sedenions suffer greater loss of algebraic properties, and are respectively eight and sixteen dimensional over the reals.

Comment: They gain properties that are useful in representing new behaviors.  For example the quaternions can be used to model 3D transformations.  I'm just sketching for you one reason the extension of number systems *may* have a natural and finite course, one that ends for mathematical limitation, not because of arbitrary taste or laziness.

Comment: @hardmath Why not then write $\mathbb{C}\subset \mathbb{H}\subset \mathbb{O}$ and instead work in the algebraic structure formed by stitching together the previous ones, like one does when they define the notion of a vector space by stitching together an abelian group of vectors with a field of scalars, I mean we don't need to have operations between any of them if we don't want. If at any point when working with octonions you find you're only dealing in this instance with octonions that are complex numbers then you can still use the field properties on those octonions. Right?

Comment: @hardmath Sorry I did not mean to convey that your example was chosen out of laziness. I really appreciate you taking the time to comment.

Comment: I didn't take any personal umbrage!  I meant that the idea of extending number systems has been a subject of research for long enough that you will have some good material to study for many years to come.

Comment: Take also a look at the [Surreals](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Surreal_number)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

We don't stop. And we even do more complicated things than simply continuing to increase in one direction. Examples of algebras that are commonly used are:

- The ring of all continuous real-valued functions on the reals
- Finite fields and $p$-adic fields. (which are basically incompatible with the real numbers)
- Cardinal and ordinal numbers (which are also incompatible with real numbers) which have a useful arithmetic, but don't even satisfy familiar algebraic properties, like $0$ being the only solution to $x = x+1$, or even $a+b = b+a$.

The real numbers have the nice properties to make them very amenable to study and to be useful as a basic building block, and have historical importance due to their relationship to Euclidean geometry (e.g. the *number line*).

Comment: Thank you for the answer, I up-voted it though I'm still unsettled about why we don't work within or use such extensions from the get go in most contexts and want to see if I can get any more input on the topic. Also I've found from experience on this website that once I accept an answer, few if any people continue to comment on it. Do you mind if I wait a while for other people to answer/comment?

Answer (score 2):

The complex numbers are complete as a metric space and algebraically closed. Since cauchy sequences of complex numbers already converge, nothing new is going to result (every sequence will be identified with one point in C already). Since it's algebraically closed, an algebraic closure is trivial and won't produce anything new.

To get something useful we'd need some new extension beyond these. Not only that but we'd like the extension to be a field and a complete metric space still, which is harder (for example quaternions are not a field since they're not commutative).

Comment: My question was not if my *particular* instance of this would provide someone with any new tools. It was if taking in general lets say field extensions and or quotients could lead to something useful then why not do it. Also not necessarily starting from $\mathbb{C}$.

Comment: In general, yes this is done when it could lead to something useful.